# Where is $V(x,y)=-2x^2(1-2y^2)-2y^4(1-x^2)$ strictly negative?

Tags: calculus

This a step in a larger problem that I'm trying to make sense of. I have the function

$$V(x,y)=-2x^2(1-2y^2)-2y^4(1-x^2).$$

In the book they say that $V<0$ in the rectangle $[-1,1]\times[-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}]$. Can someone show me why this is?

I understand that all the even powers are always positive so for $V$ to be negative I clearly want to have that $1-2y^2>0$ and $1-x^2>0$. Solving these we get that $-1/\sqrt{2}\leq y\leq 1/\sqrt{2}$ and $-1\leq x \leq 1$. However, shouldn't the rectangle then not include the endpoints? because if we allow endpoints then its not a strict inequality. So the rectangle should be $(-1,1)\times(-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$. Why am I wrong?

Comment: What are the enpoints of a rectangle? The corners and also the center (the origin) must be excluded. Can it be that you misread the book? Maybe it says that $V<0$ *only* if $(x,y) \in [-1,1]\times[-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}]$ (so it's an implication, not an equivalence)?

Comment: Yes, its only if. But I don't see how this changes anything. My point is that if $(x,y)\in [-1,1]\times[-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}]$ then if we choose $(x,y)=(1,1/\sqrt{2})$ this gives $V=0$ and not $V<0.$ By endpoints I actually meant boundary of the the rectangle.

Comment: You are right, there are points $(x,y)\in [-1,1]\times[-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}]$ such that $V(x,y)=0$ (at least five). What I meant was that maybe the book said "If $V(x,y)<0$ then…".

Answer (score 1):

$V<0$ in the rectangle $R = [-1,1]\times[-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}]$ does not mean $V \ge 0$ outside $R$. For example, you have $V < 0$ for $x = 0, y \ne 0$ as well as for $x \ne 0, y = 0$.

Anyway, let us consider $(x,y) \in R$. We certainly have $-2x^2(1-2y^2) \le 0$ and $-2y^4(1-x^2) \le 0$. In order that $V(x,y) = 0$ we need both

(1) $-2x^2(1-2y^2) = 0$, i.e. $x = 0$ or $y = \pm1/\sqrt{2}$

(2) $-2y^4(1-x^2) = 0$, i.e. $y = 0$ or $x = \pm1$

There are exactly five solutions: $x = y = 0$ and $x = \pm1, y  = \pm1/\sqrt{2}$.